Displaying layers in WMTS service in QGIS
I have a problem displaying correctly the layers provided in the WMTS service: https://testmapa.um.warszawa.pl/mapviewer/wmts?SERVICE=WMTS connected to QGIS.
There are two layers that do not render in QGIS.
One is in Mercator and can be connected to ArcGIS Pro, the
the other one in EPSG:2178 and cannot be connected in ArcGIS Pro, but in TATUK GIS it works fine.
Has anyone had a similar problem or knows how to solve it?
An important thing that when establishing a connection in QGIS to this WMTS, you need to check the Invert axis oreintation checkbox, otherwise the WTMS is located near islandia.
No information appears in the Message Panel when adding and using this service. WMTS is not showing any errors.The URL in the browser works but may not be available outside Poland.
There are already three inWMTS - WARSZAWA_POSITRON, LINDLEY, AA_SPATIAL_ST_MAPA. All layers locate correctly - to the range defined in the service, but they do not display on the map, you cannot see the tiles.

which 2 layers? what is shown in the logs? do the URLs work in the browser

please add more info.

https://epsg.org/crs_2178/ETRF2000-PL-CS2000-21.html has axes of Northing then Easting, so GIS clients that assume Easting first may have issues

That's why I check Invert axis orientation when adding this WMTS connection. This ensures that the layer is positioned in the correct place, but the tiles are not still rendering.
